# What does the 'Deploy Crew' colors means in Tharsis?

Tags: tharsis

In the 'Deploy Crew' panel (up, center), there are triangles with colors.

The triangles means how many events will happen, but what does the colors (red, green, yellow) means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It indicates the severity of the challenge event.

I think the tutorial mentions that by looking ahead at the upcoming triangles, you can get an indication of the level of disasters pending, so you can plan a bit for it.

Examples:

- Endure some damage this round if it means having extra dice or resources for use in the next when you're expecting a more critical event
- Investing in the greenhouse to have food for replenishing for an upcoming critical event (although spending time in the greenhouse is generally a good idea anyway)